# PCIe video capture card

Tags: video-capture

Is it better to go with a video capture card with h.264 encoding or just a raw input port? I have powerful pc but not sure best card to use for high quality image, reliability, and ease of install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware encoders used for best performance, not quality. So, if you don't need realtime, I suggest to use software encoder with many options.